# Google Solar API returns black TIFF images

Tags: google-maps-api, solar-radiation

I'm currently trying out the new [Google Solar API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/powering-future-our-new-solar-api?hl=en). I've been following the [guide in the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/solar/data-layers?hl=en) which gives me the described JSON as a response.

However, once I visit the returned links followed by *&key=API-KEY*, it most often returns a completely black TIFF Image, even with the example location written in the documentation (e.g. in case of the *maskUrl* or *dsmUrl* images). Only the RGB image (*rgbUrl*) is returned as a proper image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having some struggles with installing required packages, I was able to make sense of the provided API with [this Jupyter Notebook](https://leafmap.org/notebooks/80_solar/). I still don't understand the output of Google's API and some features remain hidden, but this way I can extract some of its information.
[image]